# QNEAT wrong distance

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have a problem with the QNEAT3 points to table package. My first 6 points are in the same place, so I expect a distance of 0. This is the case for 1 to 2.... 1 to 6, but for 2 to 1 I find a distance of 40 km, then I get 0 km again for 2 to 3....2 to 6 (same for point 3 with a distance with points 1 and 2, but none for 4-5-6). So I've got part of the matrix correct. I'd like to know where this problem comes from and how to fix it. If that's not possible, I'd like to have an alternative.

The network I'm working on was generated by r.drain.

I've already tried to re-install QNEAT3 with the most recent zip version.